# Authentication model choosing

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication

I need help choosing authentication model.

I have a resource,  let's say “/items" which has some attributes, like this:

```
[{
 “id”:”1234”,
 “secretInfo1”:”value1”,
 “secretInfo2”:”value2”
 “price”:”1000"
}]
```

Case 1
Api user is anonymous user.
Api user can do some operations on this resource, if he know attributes: id, secretInfo1, secretInfo2.

Case 2
Api user has account, login and password.
Api user can do some operations on this resource, if he was authenticated and authorized to access this resource.

Because of specific requirements I can't send login/password or secret attributes in each request.
For now, I see only session based authentication model for it, but it's not stateless and not recommended for REST API.
Oauth1/2 looks like overkill for it.

Could you please recommend me authentication model.